# How to predict Y_train with two different X_train data

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, nlp

This is my first time working with python on machine learning.

I have a dataset that I split into a training dataset of length of `9000` and a test dataset of a length of `1000`.
I would like to predict articles categories (Y) by articles titles (X1) and abstracts (X2)
`X_train_pad1, X_test_pad1` (Titles), `X_train_pad2,X_test_pad2` (Abstracts), `Y_train_id` and `Y_test_id` (Categories) are all of type `numpy.ndarray`,
Their shape are respectively `(9000, 36),(1000, 36),(9000, 1446),(1000, 1446),(9000,) and (1000,)`

Below are the codes for the prediction of Y_train_id (i.e. Categories) by X_train_pad1 (i.e. Titles)
and its evaluation

```
embed_dim= 128*2
dropout1 = 0.5
conv_filters= 128
conv_kernel = 2
maxpool_size = 2
dense_size = 128
batch_size = 128
epochs = 7 
vocab_size=5000
num_cat=96 #(number of categories)

model_cnn = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
# Embedding 
model_cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size,embed_dim, input_length= max_len))
# Dropout
model_cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(dropout1))
# Convolution 1
model_cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(conv_filters, conv_kernel,padding='valid', strides= 1,activation='relu'))
# Maxpooling
model_cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling1D(maxpool_size))

#Flatten
model_cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
# Dense+ Activation
model_cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(dense_size,  activation='relu'))

# Classifieur (Dense + activation softmax)
model_cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_cat))
model_cnn.add(tf.keras.layers.Activation('softmax'))

# Compiler le modèle 
model_cnn.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', 
                  optimizer='adam', 
                  metrics= ['accuracy'])
# Afficher le summary du modèle
print(model_cnn.summary())

#Model fitting
model_cnn.fit(X_train_pad1, Y_train_id, batch_size = batch_size , epochs = epochs)

#model evaluation
model_cnn.evaluate(X_test_pad1, Y_test_id)
```

I would like to fit a model (with 2 two inputs) that allows me to predict categories by titles `(X_train_pad1)` and abstract `(X_train_pad2)` at the same time and to evaluate it.

Comment: Not sure I understand you correctly - do you want a model which uses the features from both `X_train_pad1` and `X_train_pad2`? Merge them to a single variable and pass it to `fit` as you do right now with `X_train_pad1`. I don't know what are the types of `X_train_pad1` and `2`, if they are pandas dataframes for example use `pandas.merge`.

Comment: `type (X_train_pad1)= numpy.ndarray` .It is same for the other variables

Comment: So `numpy.hstack` or `numpy.concatenate`

Comment: Sorry @itaishz I don't know much about python. Can you please give me some links that I can refer to?

Comment: Sure, here's [Numpy's concatenate](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) (has a link there for `hstack` too). I think `X_train_pad_all = np.concatenate((X_train_pad1, X_train_pad2), axis=1)` should do the trick for you.

Comment: Should I also concatanate the  test datasets (i.e. `X_test_pad1` and `X_test_pad2`) to evaluate the model?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226622/discussion-between-itaishz-and-seydou-goro).